# VHDL AND multiple bit vector with a single bit

Tags: vhdl

Let's say I have a single bit std_vector called x, and 4 bit std_vector y. I want to AND all of the bits of y with x separately in a process. I know that I can do it in multiple lines like this:

```
output(3) <= y(3) and x;
output(2) <= y(2) and x;
output(1) <= y(1) and x;
output(0) <= y(0) and x;
```

But I want to do that in single line. How can I achieve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another signal where `x` is repeated as many times as needed, so that you can `and` it with the whole `y` vector at once.

```
signal xs : std_logic_vector(1 to y'length);

xs <= (others => x);
output <= y and xs;
```

I'm not sure if this can be reduced to a single line.

Or you can just write a loop:

```
for i in y'low to y'high loop
    output(i) <= y(i) and x;
end loop;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In verilog I can do something like output <= y & {4{x}};. {} is called replication operator I think. I am wondering if something similar also exist in VHDL.

Comment: Vhdl2008 allows simply `output <= y and x;`